# Simplest javascript function not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, getelementsbytagname

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="jQueryValidation.Default" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function checkValidity() {
        var container = document.getElementById("toggle");
        alert("uspeh!");
        var inputArray = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
    }
    </script>   
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="toggle">
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Vnesi ime: "></asp:Label>
        <span><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" data-errormessage="Внесете име" data-class="required"></asp:TextBox></span>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" runat="server" Text="Vnesi prezime: "></asp:Label>
        <span><asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" data-errormessage="Внесете презиме" data-class="required"></asp:TextBox></span>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblNickname" runat="server" Text="Vnesi nadimak: "></asp:Label>
        <span><asp:TextBox ID="txtNickname" runat="server" data-errormessage="Внесете надимак" data-class="required"></asp:TextBox></span>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" 
            OnClientClick="checkValidity(); return false;" onclick="btnSend_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Updated.

I have no idea why no pop-up shows up. Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *(I don't know what happened to the comments here.)* Anyway, I know you're under some time pressure, but a half hour ago @Pointy asked for exactly that (the markup rendered to the client). After that I supported his request. If you were honest when you wrote *"Any help is appreciated."*, then you need to be willing to work with us a bit.

Comment: Wait! You changed your code! now you have `OnClientClick` as well as an `onclick` that wasn't present before! The `onclick` is the typical HTML attribute for triggering javascript, but you have a different method name, and it isn't being invoked. Since you **still** haven't posted the code rendered to the client, I can only assume that you're not serious about getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<asp:button text="Click me" onclientclick="window.checkValidity();" />
```

By doing

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function checkValidity() { }
</script>
```

You declare a function to the global scope. In the context of a browser it is the same as doing:

```
window.checkValidity = function() { };
```